# Is fingerprint supported in Android devices?

Tags: android, fingerprint

I want to know if I can develop an application that users touch the screen and their fingerprint are registered. If it is possible, is there any library to store and retrieve and detect finger prints?

Comment: There are some devices that have hardware fingerprint readers, notably some Motorola phones, with their own SDK add-ons for accessing that hardware. As dwurf indicates, though, it is impossible to get a fingerprint from a touchscreen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible, current consumer touch screens cannot 'see' with that level of detail. You might have more luck using the camera but I don't know of any projects that have done this before.

Answer (score 2):

Please check below link:

http://www.diamondfortress.com/sdk

Paid SDK but we can use it with trial

Comment: We can compare captured fingerprint images with this sdk with help of Open CV

Comment: Now it is available for a 30 days trial.

Answer (score 1):

[Looks like it is now part of Android 6.0](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html).

Answer (score 0):

i do not think that exists yet.

http://www.talkandroid.com/51754-fingerprint-scanner-sdk-available-for-android-courtesy-of-xda/

Answer (score 0):

Came across this http://www.diamondfortress.com/sdk. It's a paid SDK and it uses camera. But I have not personally tried it out.