# can android phone be used as biometric finger print device

Tags: android, biometrics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is fingerprint supported in android devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369799/is-fingerprint-supported-in-android-devices)

Is it possible to use an android phone as a biometric finger print device?

Comment: you can probably scan a fingerprint using the camera, but you won't be able to use the touchscreen at all - it doesn't sense data at that level of detail.

Comment: Hm... camera hadn't occurred to me. Would be easy to fool (since you could use a 2D image) but could work. I gather there's a phone out that uses face recognition to unlock...

Comment: I think face recognition is technically a biometrics technique, and all newer Android phones do that. As for detecting fingerprints, others have mentioned that it isn't possible now.

Answer (score 2):

As in, you touch the screen and it gets your fingerprint? No. The touch screen doesn't have that kind of scanning technology. As far as Marc's comment about using the camera, that could prove very difficult. Changes in lighting will make it very hard to pick out all the lines in the fingerprint.

Answer (score 2):

No. Most touch screen devices are only capable of registering a small number of simultaneous touches - a dozen at most. So even if the resolution (accuracy of position) and sensitivity (accuracy of pressure) were sufficient, you wouldn't be able to scan enough detail.

Answer (score 0):

The only Android phone I know of that had an integrated fingerprint reader was the Motorola Atrix.  Theoretically a software application could be developed using the camera and some image processing code to accomplish this task, but I've not heard of any serious attempts.  Note that this approach is different than the novelty apps you see on the market today.
Another option would be to interface with an external finger print scanner via USB using the USB Host API: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. A quick google search turned up [this company](http://www.mobbeel.com/products/) though, they seem to offer other (iris, voice, hand geometry, signature, and apparently more) biometric security options for Android phones.

Quote from their site:

```
"MobbID is a state-of-the-art multi-biometric security solution that reliably and
securely verifies the identity of mobile phone users by using their unique features
or in combination i.e. iris, voice, face, signature, hand geometry.

Choose your best-fit biometric method or combine them for greater security and
user convenience."
```